# Fullcalendar - resources on horizontal (columns) and days with hours on vertical

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I would like to prepare calendar with resources on horizontal (columns) and days with hours on vertical. I mean to have week or month view (or infinite?) on vertical line. For exmaple:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX6bL.png)

Is there any option to realize that with fullcalendar?

Comment: At the moment, no. Feel free to submit / add your vote to a feature request... https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.